# Azure SDK DotNet equivalent of Az Resource Update

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk, azure-rest-api

I am looking to do a [az resource update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-update) using C# code, either using a http request to ARM or any SDK feature.

I am looking to reconcile an AKS cluster by using az resource update.

How can I do this via C# code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure.ResourceManager.Resources](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/1.3.1) package to create or update Azure resources. [This repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-net-management/tree/master/samples/resources) provides you samples on how to use the Azure SDK packages.

To find all the packages list of Azure SDK, you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/packages).